# Node.js video not buffering but playing

Tags: node.js, video, server, mp4

I'm starting a node.js server and i'm trying to play a video on client-side in this case the browser and every time i try to play the video the video plays but the seek bar will not buffer but the video will play if you try to seek it will just send you back to where you already were. my bet guess is that the writeHead is not writing fast enough to buffer so it a one way thing and it wont buffer before the video plays that.

server code snippet for video.mp4

```
case '/video.mp4':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("oops this doesn't exist - 404");
                response.end();
            }
            else{

                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "video/mp4", 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            }
        });
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [support byte range requests](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/). See SoundManager2's [Technical Notes on the subject](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/technotes/#byte-serving).

> Byte Serving is automatically negotiated between client and server, and offers a number of advantages over traditional downloads. Most notably, Byte Serving is closer to a "streaming" technology and enables clients to seek, buffer and resume playback at arbitrary positions within a file once the duration is known.

Example Request:

```
GET 1a8fdf5d0433ed581bbcee74836b3305.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=5210604-5275910
```

Expected Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-length: 65307
Content-Range: bytes 5210604-5275910/5275911
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

1. You don't appear to be sending the [`206 Partial Content`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.7) status.
2. You're not sending a proper `Content-Range` response header.
3. Finally if the client makes a range request that is out of bounds—that is, none of the range values overlap the extent of the resource—the server should respond with a [`416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.17) status.

Comment: Ok so i'm a little confused i don't understand what i need in specific but if i'm right i need to change the 200 to 206 and i need to have the accepted ranges but how do i do that?

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 to simplify it I would recommend using something like [send](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send). You basically need to parse the `Range` request header which will tell you the byte ranges that the client wants, then you have to send it only those bytes of the requested resource along with the correct status code and  response headers.

Comment: ok so in the end i got my code to work. but now I'm useing send it worked for a while but it stopped working now any ideas I'm getting the 206 error again?

Comment: @frenchtoaster10 can you either update your question or (preferably) accept this answer and open a new one so I can see your updated code?